# How to create the "@" character on the Logitech Craft keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

How do I create the `@` character on the Logitech Craft keyboard? I have tried the <kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>altgr</kbd> key combination, but it does not work.

The problem is: The keyboard behaves differently when it is attached to a Windows computer and to a Mac computer. And it also behaves differently when I press special keys in a Mac app and in a Windows app from a Parallels VM on that Mac!

Comment: Which model do you have. The one I looked at (Tech Radar) has the @ key above the 2 key, so Shift 2.

Comment: My Craft version has a GERMAN keyboard layout. So there is no @ character on the number 2 key. But there is a @ character on the Q key and one on the L key. But there is no PDF manual for the Craft keyboard which tells me how I can output this character.

Comment: I found it at [Cannot write the @ symbol w/ German keyboard (Windows)](https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-write-the-symbol-w-german-keyboard-windows/10839) so it might be Atom-specific, but does shift+ A umlaut work?

Comment: Maybe easier to use auto hot key

Answer (score 2):

You can use<kbd>Alt</kbd> + 4-digit numeric keypad combos on most applications.

**Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>**, press <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> on the **numeric keypad** (for laptops without a numeric keypad, you may need to hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd>) in sequence, then release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

This works to compose most characters, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> for the section sign, §, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> for the non-breakng space, useful in HTML.

Since some applications steal key-presses, though, it does not work everywhere.

Comment: Isn't there a SIMPLE way by pressing one or maximally two keys?

Comment: Your answer does not work: I have tried every alt key on the keyboard.

Comment: have you tried : (left)  Ctrl + Alt + Q  or  Ctrl + Alt + L
(right)  Alt Gr + Ctrl + Q  or  Alt Gr + Ctrl + L

Comment: @DrRedAnt, thank you, `(left) Ctrl + Alt + Q` does work! But it seems you misspelled the rest of your comment?

Comment: Isn't there an explaining PDF manual for the Craft Keyboard and for its different language keyboard layouts? I have searched for it but I didn't find any.

Comment: @DrRedAnt, please write an answer, so I can vote for it.

Comment: thought so........................................................

Comment: This 0064 method does not work on my keyboard here!

Comment: Now, `(left) Ctrl + Alt + Q` does not work anymore! Now, `(left) Ctrl + Alt + Q` locks the computer, so I have to reenter my computer password!

Answer (score 0):

EASY ANSWER: German keyboard (for subscript signs) @, €, etc...

PRESS: all together (bottom left corner keys)
STRG + Alt + (key needed)(Q/@)

Ta-da!!

My first time in Germany , I could not figure it out, and would have to keep copy pasting the subscript @,€ signs...

Finally

Btw: European STRG (string) is like the equivalent of CNTRL